# Can we use @MagicConstant annotation in our code?

Tags: android-studio

When im developing Android Applications i come to realize that the usual is to avoid enums due to performance.

So i would like to know, can we use the @MagicConstant in our own code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what i was looking for Android Studio since 19.01 of the support library has the annotations library which is handy for catching errors

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations

The @IntDef was what i was looking for